# Is it possible to run unit tests when loading dependent assemblies at run-time?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

Is it possible to run unit tests without 'copy local' on the dependencies, loading the assemblies in run-time?

More details:

My .net solution looks like this:

- MainProject (exe) [depends on 'Class1Project' and load it at runtime using 'AssemblyLoaderProject'].

  'Class1Project' set to 'copy local = false' and 'AssemblyLoaderProject' set to 'copy local = true'
- Class1Project (dll)
- AssemblyLoaderProject (load and resolve dependencies assemblies at runtime using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve and Assembly.LoadFrom)
- UnitTestsProject (either Nunit or MSTest)

In the unit tests project i'm trying to test 'Class1Project' and i wish to set its configuration the same as MainProject.

Meaning, the UnitTestProject also reference 'Class1Project' with 'copy local = false' and 'AssemblyLoaderProject' with 'copy local = true', and use it to load assemblies in runtime.

But for some reason the unit tests could not execute, the runner throw FileNotFoundException specifing that it couldn't resolve the 'Class1Project' assembly.

Trying to debug it and i see that the test runner doesn't even get to the code that tell AssemblyLoaderProject to load the assemblies.

The test code looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Loader.LoadAssemblies();
        Class1 cls = new Class1();
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

This is the error message i get when trying to debug it with VS2012 test runner on MSTest:

```
Test Name:  TestMethod1
Test FullName:  UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
Test Source:    c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs : line 13
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.1177608

Result Message: 
Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = \user
LOG: DisplayName = ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/ClassLibrary1/UnitTestProject1/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : UnitTestProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/ClassLibrary1/UnitTestProject1/bin/Debug/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/ClassLibrary1/UnitTestProject1/bin/Debug/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/ClassLibrary1/UnitTestProject1/bin/Debug/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/ClassLibrary1/UnitTestProject1/bin/Debug/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.EXE.
Result StackTrace:  at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Loader.LoadAssemblies` is the method that signs up for the `AssemblyResolve` event, you are receiving this exception because the runtime cannot find `ClassLibrary1.dll` via probing. It is important to understand why probing is coming into play here. Probing is invoked because before you can load the any assemblies via `Loader.LoadAssemblies` the method must be Jitted. To be properly jitted, the runtime must load the assemblies for types referenced at compile-time. Since you have turned 'copy local' to false the file `ClassLibrary1.dll` is not copied and not in the probing path. Hence, your `FileNotFoundException`.

First, I would try moving `Loader.LoadAssemblies` into a method marked with the `TestInitialize` attribute to run before each test. However, depending on the where the files are copied before test execution, this may not work either. You may have to enable deployment in the test settings and use the `DeploymentItem` attribute.

A bigger question is: If you are unit testing, why can't you set 'copy local' to true for the dependencies so they are copied with the test assemblies?

Depending on exactly what `Loader.LoadAssemblies` does, you may encounter other issues caused by assemblies being loaded into multiple or different load contexts. This can cause problems like `InvalidCastException` where the error says you cannot cast type 'X' to type 'X'. However, you may be safe because AppDomain.AssemblyResolve will be called to load an assembly into the Load context if it is not found via probing.

Comment: Calling 'Loader.LoadAssemblies' in TestInitialize method worked in this case. The loader use full path to load the class1project, so i don't need to use copy local or enable deployment. Can you address situation where my test project contains a class that derived from Class1 (which reside in Class1Project)? in this case the jit and probing phase happens when I try to load the assembly in the test runner, and it will failed.

Comment: if i do the same in my main .exe assembly, creates a class that derived from Class1, the application will run just fine. does it try to JIT the derived class only when first accessing it (which happens after the Lodaer run), and in the test context the test runner try to JIT all the assembly's types when the file load? perhaps in-order to parse which one contains tests?

Comment: @avivr I believe you are exactly right. The test framework is loading all  types in the test project, looking for tests. This happens before `TestInitialize` so `LoadAssemblies` has not run before probing happens and the same exception is thrown.

Comment: @avivr I will ask again: Why can you not simply set 'copy local' to true. Your tests are obviously compiled against Class1Project and setting it to false is causing all kinds of problems. If you want to test realistic, integration scenarios, then create *two* test projects. One with a reference to Class1Project (pure unit tests) and one without a reference to it that loads it dynamically (integration/component tests).

Answer (score 1):

I agree there should be a way to configure the resolving directories, same as Mstest does using ".runsettings" file.

About the question :

> *A bigger question is: If you are unit testing, why can't you set 'copy local' to true for the dependencies so they are copied with the test assemblies?*

Well, the answer is that a lot of dependencies of dependencies might be used.

It is hard to follow all the passive dependencies like 3rd parties.

I mean - if your tested assembly is depended on assembly A, that A could be depended on B.
copy local true will copy only A, but will fail in runtime because B is missing.
Consider cases like the whole assmeblies are in nested in folders like:

- AppRoot

  - AppHost.exe
  - BuisnessLogic (folder)
  - Interfaces (folder)
  - UI (folder)
  - Infrastracture (folder)
  - 3rdParty (folder)

And the apphost has App.config which allowes directory probing to make the runtime resolve all nested directories.

The mstest ".runsettings" can configure similar assemblies probing during unit tests.
XUnit can't do that.

One workaround is starting referencing to your test a lot of assmeblies, each one after you find it can't be reslove - but you find it only when running the test.

This is a bad and frastrating solution.

I vote for insergting a change request that XUnit will support directories probing configuration as well.

That would be very helpful.

(that actually what blocks us upgrading from mstest to the desired XUnit).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make that the DLL'Class1Project' is available for the loader, so, if you don't want to set the project to always copy it, you could use the **[DeploymenItem](http://goo.gl/7DJ1n)** attribute to copy it for the test, so that the load can find it.

Comment: The loader use Assembly.LoadFrom(FULL_PATH_TO_Class1ProjectDll), so it should be available to it anywhere without copying the file.

Answer (score 0):

[There is a bug in VS2012 test runner.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771138/vs2012-referenced-assemblies-in-unit-test-are-not-copied-to-the-unit-test-out-f) In my project I have all dependencies set to copy local = true and there are still some dlls which don't get copied to the "Out" folder, making the tests fail. If I run the same tests under VS2010 everything runs perfectly.

Using DeploymentAttribute does help but it shouldn't be required.